# input parameter to mysql syntax on C#

Tags: c#, mysql

I try to input value but @numVal  doest not work ( on the line begin with arr[10] )

```
using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;
    using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;

    namespace ConsoleApplication2
    {
        class Program
        {
            static void Main(string[] args)
            {


                MySqlConnection conDatabase = new MySqlConnection("Data Source=localhost;" +
                                           "Persist Security Info=yes;" +
                                           "UserId=tee; PWD=t5794849; database=ph3;");
                conDatabase.Open();
               // MySqlCommand cmdDatabase = new MySqlCommand("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `q_mem_sur`; create table q_mem_sur as SELECT Count(*) As rowa,  member.Ssurname,  Sum(Case When ((member.status = '1')) Then 1 Else 0 End) As Status11 From member Group By member.Ssurname Order By rowa Desc;", conDatabase);


                Console.WriteLine("Enter username");
                string input = Console.ReadLine();

                try
                {
                  int  numVal = Convert.ToInt16(input);
                }
                catch (FormatException )
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Input string is not a sequence of digits.");
                }
                catch (OverflowException )
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("The number cannot fit in an Int32.");
                }






                string[] arr = new string[11];
                arr[0] = "UPDATE `member` SET `amphurecode`= SUBSTRING(member.own,3,4)";
                arr[1] = "UPDATE `member` SET `provincecode`= SUBSTRING(member.own,3,2)";
                arr[2] = "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `q_mem_tim`; create table q_mem_tim as SELECT member.idmember, member.own, member.provincecode, province.PROVINCE_NAME, member.amphurecode, amphur.AMPHUR_NAME, member.novote, member.Sname, member.Ssurname, member.Hno, member.Moo, member.Sex, member.tambol, member.dateofbirth, member.migratedate, Year( Current_Date( ) ) -  Year( member.dateofbirth ) AS y,  DATEDIFF('2011-08-01',(migratedate)) AS d FROM member LEFT JOIN amphur ON ( member.amphurecode  = amphur.AMPHUR_CODE ) LEFT JOIN province ON member.provincecode  = province.PROVINCE_CODE";
                arr[3] = "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `q_mem_sur`; create table q_mem_sur as SELECT Count(*) As rowa,  member.Ssurname,  Sum(Case When ((member.status = '1')) Then 1 Else 0 End) As Status11 From member Group By member.Ssurname Order By rowa Desc";
                arr[4] = "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `q_mem_hno` ; create table q_mem_hno as select member.Hno, member.Moo, member.tambol, COUNT( member.Hno ) AS cntHno, COUNT(DISTINCT member.Ssurname) as NoSur FROM member GROUP BY member.Hno, member.Moo, member.tambol ORDER BY cntHno DESC  ";
                arr[5] = "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `q_pro_ori`; create table q_pro_ori as Select member.provincecode,   count(*) As cnt  From member Group By member.provincecode Order By cnt Desc ";
                arr[6] = "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `q_am_ori`; create table q_am_ori as Select member.amphurecode,  member.provincecode,  count(*) As cnt  From member Group By member.amphurecode, member.provincecode Order By cnt Desc ";
                arr[7] = "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `Sur_Hno_`; create table Sur_Hno_ as SELECT count( *  ) , Ssurname, q_mem_tim.Hno, q_mem_tim.Moo, q_mem_tim.tambol FROM q_mem_tim GROUP BY q_mem_tim.Ssurname, q_mem_tim.Hno, q_mem_tim.Moo, q_mem_tim.tambol ORDER BY count( * ) DESC";
                arr[8] = "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `q_dup_own`; create table q_dup_own as SELECT Count(*) as n ,member.own FROM member GROUP BY member.own order by n DESC ";
            //  arr[9] = "drop table if exists q_mem_birth; create table q_mem_birth as SELECT member.idmember, member.own, member.provincecode, province.PROVINCE_NAME, member.amphurecode, amphur.AMPHUR_NAME, member.Sname, member.Ssurname, member.Hno, member.Moo, member.Sex, member.tambol, member.dateofbirth, member.migratedate, member.fathercode , member.mathercode,   Year( Current_Date( ) ) -  Year( member.dateofbirth ) AS y,  DATEDIFF('2011-08-01',(migratedate)) AS d ,member.inputstaf  FROM member LEFT JOIN amphur ON ( member.amphurecode  = amphur.AMPHUR_CODE ) LEFT JOIN province ON member.provincecode  = province.PROVINCE_CODE WHERE DAYOFYEAR(member.dateofbirth)-DAYOFYEAR(NOW())  < 30 and DAYOFYEAR(member.dateofbirth)-DAYOFYEAR(NOW())  > -1 order by DAYOFYEAR(member.dateofbirth)";
                arr[9] = "ALTER TABLE `q_mem_tim` ADD `agec` VARCHAR( 10 )  NULL ";
            //    arr[10] = "UPDATE q_mem_birth SET agec = CASE WHEN y < 10 THEN 'ด'  WHEN y > 10 and y < 20 and Sex='ญ' THEN  'วญ'  WHEN y > 10 and y < 20 and Sex='ช' THEN  'วช'   ELSE 'ผญ' END";
                arr[10] = "drop table if exists q_mem_birth; create table q_mem_birth as SELECT q_mem_tim.idmember,q_mem_tim.own,q_mem_tim.PROVINCE_NAME,q_mem_tim.AMPHUR_NAME,q_mem_tim.novote,q_mem_tim.Sname,q_mem_tim.Ssurname,q_mem_tim.Hno,q_mem_tim.Moo,q_mem_tim.Sex,q_mem_tim.tambol,q_mem_tim.dateofbirth,q_mem_tim.migratedate,q_mem_tim.y,q_mem_tim.d,q_mem_tim.agec FROM q_mem_tim where  q_mem_tim.dateofbirth is not null and q_mem_tim.dateofbirth != '00000000' and day(q_mem_tim.dateofbirth) != '00' and day(q_mem_tim.dateofbirth) > 0 and day(q_mem_tim.dateofbirth) < 11 and month(q_mem_tim.dateofbirth) != '00'   and month(q_mem_tim.dateofbirth) = @numVal order by tambol,Moo, month(dateofbirth),day(dateofbirth)  "; 


                foreach (string s in arr)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(s);
                    MySqlCommand cmdDbase = new MySqlCommand((s), conDatabase);
                    cmdDbase.CommandTimeout = 500;
                    cmdDbase.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
                conDatabase.Close();
            }

            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1)Truncate the tables; don't drop them and remake them because when you drop them you have to do the indexes and add the Primary Keys again.

```
using(var cm = _dbConnection.CreateCommand())
{
    cm.CommandText = @"Truncate Table Table";
    cm.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    cm.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

2)Don't forget the `@` symbol; it helps with anything SQL:

```
    using(var cm = _dbConnection.CreateCommand())
    {
        cm.CommandText = @"Select * 
                           From table 
                           Where Id = @Id";
        cm.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        cm.Parameter.AddWithValue("Id", id);
        cm.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
```

I know you're not doing it this way and you're using a string array (just put a foreach loop outside the using statement and replace the cm.CommandText value with the string's value) but with the examples it should help you or at least give you some ideas.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a `MySqlParameter` to the command named `numVal`.